# Can we assign crystal report to microsoft report viewer?

Tags: c#, reporting-services, crystal-reports

I have made a crystal report in Sap crystal reports. Now i want to assign it to a microsoft report viewer. Remember that crystal report document and crystal report viewer is not showing in my c# window forms application. I have made a form and put report viewer of microsoft on that form. Now i want that when the form_loads, crystal report should be shown in report viewer. I have made a folder and put crystal report in that folder in my c# window forms project. It is a embedded resource. I have given Report Viewr the path too. When i Call show method on report viewer like ReportViewer.Show(), it says that "Report definition is not valid or not supported by this version of reporting services." Any Idea??

Comment: If you want to use Crystal Reports, you should use Crystal Reports. Microsoft Report Viewer is something else. You cannot expect them to be compatible.

Comment: Have a look at this link : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12694/Creating-Crystal-Reports-using-C-with-Datasets